# Javascript's setInterval lags the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a live chat working on. And I have used setInterval to display all messages in realtime every 0.5 seconds. But I noticed that setInterval freezes and sometimes crashes the browser. I heard that setTimeout is the best alternative way to use?

```
  setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_msg.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {conn:conn},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#chatarea').html(data);
            }
        });
    },500);
```

Comment: If you are hammering the server with a new request ever half second, no wonder it is grinding to a halt. As @synthet1c says in their answer, wait for the previous request to finish before starting another one. I would also suggest a longer delay like 1000ms or more if you are downloading the whole conversation every time instead of just the new items. Doing something like sending a timestamp of the last update and filtering on the server-side, sending back only new data, would save a lot of bandwidth and make responses much quicker. Sending everything will become increasingly slower over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using `setTimeout` which will wait for the previous request to resolve before requesting the data again.

```
(function pollMessages() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "display_msg.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      conn: conn
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#chatarea').html(data);
      setTimeout(pollMessages, 500)
    }
  });
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `setInterval` will call the function every x milliseconds, and, as you are submitting requests, and the server takes some time to respond, it might happen that multiple requests are executing in parallel, causing some trouble to you app.

With `setTimeout` you could submit a new request only after the completion of the previous one. This will be much better. Don't forget to write some code to treat timeout problems.

Good luck!